# Restricting AWS Identity Pool to access single Lambda only

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

I have a web UI which is granted unauthenticated access to AWS Translate via the AWS Javascript SDK and an AWS Identity Pool (it's just a prototype for now, I'll be adding authentication shortly).

The Cloudformation for the Identity Pool looks like this -

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  AppName:
    Type: String
Outputs:
  IdentityPoolId:
    Value: !Ref IdentityPool  # returns id
Resources:
  IdentityPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPool
    Properties:
      AllowUnauthenticatedIdentities: true
      IdentityPoolName: !Sub ${AppName}-identity
  UnauthRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
            Condition:
              "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": unauthenticated
              StringEquals:
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": !Ref IdentityPool
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Federated: cognito-identity.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/TranslateFullAccess
      Path: /
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  RoleMapping:
    Properties:
      IdentityPoolId: !Ref IdentityPool
      Roles:
        unauthenticated: !GetAtt UnauthRole.Arn
    Type: AWS::Cognito::IdentityPoolRoleAttachment
```

and everything works fine.

Now however I want to insert some logic between the web page and Translate. So I have set up a Lambda which intercepts the request, calls Translate via `boto3`, adds my new logic and returns the augmented translation.

I've also changed the managed policy in the above from `TranslateFullAccess` to `AWSLambdaReadOnlyAccess`.

Now I see that the Javascript SDK has a method to invoke a Lambda function given an ARN -

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property

but I'm slightly concerned this could be abused by someone who knows my Identity Pool id and could therefore theoretically call *any* of my Lambdas if they know an ARN.

So - is there any way within the Identity Pool Cloudformation code to restrict access to a single Lambda only ? If someone gives unauthenticated access to Lambdas via an Identity Pool, how should the scope of that access be restricted ? Or am I being over- paranoid here (how would anyone know my ARNs ?)

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH I gave up on this. Confused as to what represents am IAM User in a situation where you are using Cognito Identity pool unauthenticated role only, and not a Cognito User pool. I rolled back to using an API Gateway instead, which worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your application users exist in a user pool. You've added the relevant user pool to an identity pool, so you will be able to grant your application users access to some of your AWS services.

The way you do it, is by creating an IAM role for this identity pool.
In this IAM role, with the action `'execute-api:Invoke'`, you can specify the relevant resource, which will be the API gateway path to your lambda.

Keep in mind that by doing so, all of the users in the user pools which are associated with this identity pool, will be able to hit this lambda.

Example (source: [IAM Policy Examples for API Execution Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-iam-policy-examples-for-api-execution.html)):

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "execute-api:Invoke"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:*:a123456789/test/POST/mydemoresource/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: So I can't do this anonymously with just an Identity Pool? Also I don't have an API Gateway, the Javascript SDK invokes the Lambda directly.

Comment: You can use `"Action": "lambda:InvokeFunction"` with `"Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:<region>:<123456789012>:function:<example_function>"`. What do you mean by 'with just an identity pool'?

Comment: Ah that looks more like it! By "just an Identity Pool", I mean just that. There is no user pool in the example. I'm using the unauthenticated functionality within the Identity pool. Not saying this is optimal, just what I have at the moment - it's a prototype